# UICollectionView layout - device orientation change after going to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` with `horizontal scrolling` and `paging`. The cells should be the screen size always, so when the orientation of the device changes there is the call `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` and the `item size` and `collection view offset` get recalculated and it works well.

The issue occurs when going to another view controller, then rotating and going back to the view controller with the collection view. Then it looks like the collection view doesn't take into account the orientation change or something like this and there could be two cells visible, which should not happen. Also there is some weird animation when going back to the view controller with the collection view. How should these be fixed?

Here is some code:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in

    }) { (context) in

    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return collectionView.frame.size
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

    let width = collectionView.frame.size.width
    let visibleCells = collectionView.visibleCells
    if visibleCells.count == 0 {
        return CGPoint.zero
    }
    let cell = visibleCells[0]
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
    let index = indexPath?.item
    let offsetX = CGFloat(index!) * width
    let offsetY: CGFloat = 0
    let offset = CGPoint(x: offsetX, y: offsetY)

    return offset

}
```

Trying to fix the issue I make the following calls in `viewDidAppear` but no luck:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    collectionView.layoutSubviews()
}
```

Comment: Try it in `viewWillAppear`. Also call `layoutIfNeeded` instead of `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Just tried it. This gets rid of the animation but there are still two cells visible instead of the one that should show.

Comment: Did you set the new size?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri No, this is part of the problem. The cells get their size according to the size of the collectionView. But at this moment it looks like the collection view still has the size from the previous orientation of the device. So the item size does not get set properly. I have implemented `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize`

Comment: Is that delegate being called? If it is, what is the collectionView size?

Comment: Yes, it is. After being in portrait, going to the other view controller, changing to landscape and going back the collection view has a size of (320.0, 568.0) when it is being asked for the cell size at first then it switches to (568.0, 320.0)

Comment: try calling collectionView.reloadData() in  viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)  instead of  invalidateLayout() &  collectionView.layoutSubviews()

Comment: @JenJose I tried it, but the issues stay.